# rails activerecord sum works with .each but not with others

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I am trying to calculate balance in activerecords, one works and the other doesnt.

1=> why is this does not work to get the balance:

```
@accounts_balances = Account.select('(sum("in")) - (sum("out")) as balance_amount')
puts "exist #{@accounts_balances.exists?}"
puts "balance: #{@accounts_balances.balance_amount}"
```

error:

```
undefined method `balance_amount' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Account id: nil>]>
```

2=> while this works:

```
Account.select('(sum("in")) - (sum("out")) as balance_amount').each do |value|
  puts value.balance_amount
end
```

I don't like to use `.each` in no.2, and would prefer someway to execute the sql statement and grab the balance. whats the problem?

Comment: The first query returns an `AR relation` which is an array.You should be doing `puts "balance: #{@accounts_balances.first.balance_amount}"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below will work :

```
@accounts_balances[0].balance_amount
```

Actually `@accounts_balances` is not a `ActiveRecord` object. `@accounts_balances` is collection of `ActiveRecord` objects. You need to extract the `ActiveRecord` object from the collection.

Look the below example :-

I have a `Comment` model.

```
arup@linux-wzza:~/Rails/model_prac> rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 4.1.4)
Comment.first
# => #<Comment id: 1, value_old: "I am a good Boy.", value_new: "I am a bad Boy.", created_at: "2014-08-02 17:36:14", updated_at: "2014-08-02 18:21:42">
```

Now see, `#select` method giving us a [`ActiveRecord::Relation`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html) object. It means it is a collection of `ActiveRecord` objects.

```
Comment.select("value_old")
# => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Comment id: nil, value_old: "I am a good Boy.">, #<Comment id: nil, value_old: nil>]>
Comment.select("value_old").class
# => Comment::ActiveRecord_Relation
```

You can now get those `ActiveRecord` object from the collection like [`Array#[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D) method.

```
Comment.select("value_old")[0]
# => #<Comment id: nil, value_old: "I am a good Boy.">
Comment.select("value_old")[0].class
# => Comment(id: integer, value_old: text, value_new: text, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
```

Thus, `Comment.select("value_old")[0]` is giving you actually `ActiveRecord` object. Now you can call the automatic *getter* methods, which Rails gives you. Look below :-

```
Comment.select("value_old")[0].value_old
# => "I am a good Boy."
```

Below is not working, the reason I said above. As it is a *collection*.

```
Comment.select("value_old").value_old
# undefined method `value_old' for #<Comment::ActiveRecord_Relation:0xa780e88>
```

## Why `#each` method work ?

Reason is -  When you are calling `#each`, inside the block, it passes *one AR* object in every iteration and once you have the *AR* object in your hand, you can call the *getter* method as well, which I have shown above.

```
Comment.select("value_old").each { |r| p r.class }
# => Comment(id: integer, value_old: text, value_new: text, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
# => Comment(id: integer, value_old: text, value_new: text, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
```